# One to many LSTM in Keras

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, keras, recurrent-neural-network

Is it possible to implement a one-to-many LSTM in Keras?
If yes, can you please provide me with a simple example?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's possible with a `RepeatVector` layer. For example:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(10, input_shape=(1))
model.add(RepeatVector(10))
model.add(LSTM(1, return_sequences=True))
```

Then - the input shape is `(1)` and the output is `(10, 1)`.

Comment: But this just repeat the input to make it match the output time step length, right?

Comment: And it also goes through the LSTM layer. You could provide more LSTM layers. This architecture is an example of a one-to-many architecture.

Comment: Thank you for you explanation